# Create a String array from multiple Integer Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck in the following problem from a long time -

I want to create a String array StrTime from 3 Int arrays.

**Input Arrays**

```
int Time1[]={"1.1","2.1","4.1"};
int Time2[]={"2.5","4.7","5.1"};
int Time3[]={"12.55","1.11","2.1"};

CurrentTime = 2.0;
```

So loop though each integer array, check Time1, the first array item which is greater than 2.0 should be put in our String array, Noe check Time2 for the same and Time3.

At end we should get output String array as -

**Output Array**

```
String strTime[] ={"2.1","None","2.1"}
```

Can someone help me????

## UPDATE:

Also is there a way to create a double [] like below-\
{1,2,,3,4,,5}

Comment: that should not compile. You are assigning `int[]` a `String[]`!!!

Comment: The array initialization won't compile and - shouldn't the output be `{"2.1", "2.5", "12.55"}` if I get your requirements right...

Comment: @Nishant. Yes, because of that fact, I would also call it DIFFICULT

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a typo, but that's the way to init the arrays (they should be `double`):

```
double time1[]={1.1, 2.1, 4.1};
double time2[]={2.5, 4.7, 5.1};
double time3[]={12.55, 1.11, 2.1};
```

Hints:

- create a new `String` array for the result
- `for`-loop through the first array
- compare the current value with your threshold, `if` the current value is greater then store it in the first slot of the string array (need to convert it to string), and `break` out of the loop.
- repeat the last to steps for the other two arrays

Comment: How to convert that to String.

Comment: `String intAsString = "" + intValue;` - this is the simplest solution for this problem.

Comment: BTW - why did you add that update to your question? The answer to that is in my and in Reimus' answers.. Haven't you read it?

Answer (score 1):

When you get it compiling, you could use `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils` and `org.apache.commons.collection.Predicate` to filter without loops.

```
CollectionUtils.find( getACollectionOfYourArray() , new Predicate() {
            public boolean evaluate(Object val) {
                // if is gt 2
                return true;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Hehe. This answer does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    double time1[]={1.1, 2.1, 4.1};
    double time2[]={2.5, 4.7, 5.1};
    double time3[]={12.55, 1.11, 2.1};
```